# When will DBA show up on the data.se for querying?

Tags: support

I bet we could all have great fun querying against SE's data, doing similar things like http://data.stackexchange.com/serverfault/s/1802/find-identical-titles-no-closed-questions

But I noticed DBA isn't listed as an option to query against. Is there a timeframe before a site recently graduated can be queried against?

Comment: I know they are updated every month to six weeks or so, so you'll have to wait at least until then. If there isn't an entry by the end of September then we should ask again for sure.

Comment: Yes, I was just looking for it there too. Can't wait to get my hands on some data.

Comment: I did not know that querying ability was there...now I do :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, the [latest Data Dump](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/09/creative-commons-data-dump-sep-11/) has recently been released, and with it the stats on this site. Data Explorer hasn't been updated yet, but it would be fair to assume it'll be ready soon, and at that time your site will be available to browse on Data Explorer. ♪

---

**UPDATE**

In case anyone missed it, Data Explorer has updated, and [DBA is now in the roster](http://data.stackexchange.com/database%20administrators/queries). Enjoy! ♪

Comment: thanks for the heads up!

Comment: a whole week and still not up :(

Comment: There's a reason I never gave a solid estimate on how long "soon" would be ♪